# mysql columns values are mixed after upload

Tags: sql, mysql, upload, sql-update, mixed

How do we update the table most effective way if 2 columns were uploaded incorrectly? After the upload I receive that some of the values from Name column moved to id column and vise versa.
the result of the upload :

| Name | id | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| didi | 6666666 | 30 |
| miki | 7777777 | 27 |
| reg | 5647899 | 32 |
| Gimi | 1234567 | 23 |
| 1234566 | Hani | 40 |

How do I change in the last row between id and name value effectively?

Tried to update with value from name to Id - then id is erased and vise versa. Thanks

Comment: I assum e you are loading from something like a CSV file? First guess is that one column does not have a Name and therefore everything after that gets shifted left by one column.

Comment: Although this looks like you may have one row without a Name or an Age. Check your input data.

Comment: Also it would be useful to see how you are loading this and an example of the input a well

Comment: How do you/we know what result you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test (Name VARCHAR(64),    id VARCHAR(64), Age INT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('didi',    '6666666',  30),
('miki',    '7777777',  27),
('reg',     '5647899',  32),
('Gimi',    '1234567',  23),
('1234566', 'Hani',     40);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| Name | id | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| didi | 6666666 | 30 |
| miki | 7777777 | 27 |
| reg | 5647899 | 32 |
| Gimi | 1234567 | 23 |
| 1234566 | Hani | 40 |

```
UPDATE test 
  SET id=(@id:=id), id=name, name=@id
  WHERE name NOT REGEXP '[^\\d]';
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| Name | id | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| didi | 6666666 | 30 |
| miki | 7777777 | 27 |
| reg | 5647899 | 32 |
| Gimi | 1234567 | 23 |
| Hani | 1234566 | 40 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/udg874H9)